# CloudFormation parameters best practice

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, aws-cloudformation, devops

I want to set up a cloudformation stack with things such as VPCs, subnets, IGWs, etc...

A template i found online has these pre-filled and in YAML notation. In YAML, I set the default value of e.g. the CIDR block to be "x.x.x.x/16" (as an example) and I saved the YAML file.

I uploaded the YAML file to an s3 bucket, and used Azure DevOps to run a pipeline and execute the job on my AWS Account. The stack created successfully.

In this instance, I was told that its not good to "hardcode" the parameters in the YAML file. What is the best practice then?

Secondly, is there a way I can pass parameters from azure devops pipeline to the template file instead of having to insert the parameters IN the file, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was told that its not good to "hardcode" the parameters in the YAML file. What is the best practice then?

This really depends on the context.

Is the template being used for testing in a CI/CD environment and shouldn't require human intervention? Then it's perfectly fine to have hardcoded variables for VPCs, subnets, etc. In that scenario in fact, you probably don't even want to have parameters in the first place.

Is the template meant to be used by different users who perhaps want to deploy the template in different AWS accounts? Then the template shouldn't make any assumptions and you let the user choose every parameter as needed by your stack.

> Secondly, is there a way I can pass parameters from azure devops pipeline to the template file instead of having to insert the parameters IN the file, if that makes sense?

I imagine that in your pipeline you are deploying the template by running `aws cloudformation create-stack...`, in which case you can use `--parameters` to specify the parameters. See the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/create-stack.html) for more info.